# Auto reload application does not work for changes in XHTML files

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, spring-boot, facelets, hotdeploy

I created a spring boot application using spring initializer. It was working okay and configured my intellij IDE to auto reload using devtools dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It was working fine. Then I configured my application for jsf support. After this auto reload is not working any more. For every single changes in xhtml pages and classes I have to rerun everything.

I tried several solutions but nothing working so far. I have the code here
https://github.com/shiblybcc/springjsp

Is there any way to auto reload every changes I make to my application without manually doing rerun?

I am on linux, using intellij IDE, spring boot and jsf, maven.

Comment: I already have that configuration in my web.xml

Comment: `I configured my application for JSF support`. What changes have you made?

Comment: Check the 3 java files here,   https://github.com/shiblybcc/springjsp/tree/master/src/main/java/com/example
Also added some dependency and this line in pom.xml '<outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>']